# Output SOME text from grep

Tags: search, grep, output

I would like to execute a command, search the output for a line and output some of the text on that line to a variable

```
pactl list short sinks | grep <search-term>
```

Then I would like to output some of the resulting text to a variable

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: a simple `blah=\`pactl list short sinks | grep alsa\``  will store the output of command into variable blah.  replace blah with your own variable; and 'alsa'  with your <search-term>.   the backticks cause the command enclosed to be executed and output replace...

Comment: By default, grep outputs matching *lines* - but you can change that with the `-o` (`--only-matching`) option - see `man grep`

Comment: Read `man grep`. The `-o` option restricts the output to the matched string. If you want something more complex, you can postprocess the matched line. `myvar="$(pactl list short sinks | grep <search-term>| sed -e 's/unwanted//')"`

Comment: If you say what exactly you want to get from the `pactl` output, I could write the exact command for you. It will probably involve using `grep -oP`.